# Dialog box not loading the correct values-- JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a div under that I have few elements like radio buttons, list boxes etc.
When user clicks on a button we are putting that div in a dialog box and showing it as pop up.
Here the issue is, when we set any data to the elements (like changing the value, or selecting check boxes )
It is not reflecting in the popup.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!--dialog -->
<div id="edit">
            <div id="dialog_contents">
            </div>
</div>

<div id="abc123">
lisbox...name="editListBox" id="editListBox"
checkbox..name="editCheckBox"  id="editCheckBox"
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function edit()
{
        $("#editListBox" ).val('3');
        $("#editCheckBox").attr( 'checked', true );
        var data =  $("#abc123" ).html();
        $('#dialog_contents').html(data);
        $(edit).removeClass('hide').dialog('open');
}


    $('#edit').dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 650,
            height: 750,
            cache: false,
            position:'center',
            open: function(event, ui) {

                window.setTimeout(function()
                        { jQuery(document) .unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay') .unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay') ; }, 100);
            },
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {

                },
                "Edit": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
            }               
        });
```

Only problem is , whatever the values i'm setting in the js function are not reflecting in the pop up. When i print them or display it in the main screen it is showing them correctly.

P.S Attached sample code, ignore the syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
In my case , when i add the existing div to another div.
I'm having duplicate names,So when i tried to set values to those fields using name or id, its not giving me the element(may be because of ambiguity).

When i changed from id to class, the problem got resolved, i can find any element now and change its value.